# Returning a fixed variable of a function for procedure use in VBA

Tags: vba, function, return-value, procedure

I am writing a piece of VBA code that Rolls a dice. I have the dice Rolling function complete. The function ThePoint() I want it to look to see if the dice total matches 4,5,6,8,9,10. If so then sets intPoint to that number.

My problem is I want to use the value of intPoint elsewhere in my program as a fixed number. For example, if intPoint = 6, I only want to return that value, the 6, to a sub procedure. I can call ThePoint, however, then it sets a new value of intPoint. Any help is appreciated.

```
Function ThePoint() As Integer
    Dim intPoint As Integer
    Do Until intPoint
        Select Case RollDice()
            Case 4
                intPoint = 4
            Case 5
                intPoint = 5
            Case 6
                intPoint = 6
            Case 8
                intPoint = 8
            Case 9
                intPoint = 9
            Case 10
                intPoint = 10
        End Select
    Loop
    ThePoint = intPoint
    Debug.Print ThePoint
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = ThePoint
    Debug.Print x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your RollDice() function as

```
Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
```

In your case for 1d10 (10 sided dice):

```
Function RollDice()
    RollDice = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
End Function
```

Now you should have the same outputs.